# Meta Stack Exchange stats pages for non-existent review queues

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, review-stats

It is possible to go directly to a URL for a stats page for a queue type that does not exist on meta sites. Clicking "start reviewing now" on these pages leads to a Page Not Found error.

Examples:

- https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats

Is it supposed to be possible to navigate to such pages?